# Ajax API call showing response but not executing function in success method

Tags: json, ajax, get, jsonp, getjson

Having trouble with a simple API call that returns some JSON. The page gets a response from the server with the JSON I am requesting, I confirmed this from looking in the Network section of the developer tools, however I have had no luck with the success method. I cannot get anything to print to console or a function to work. Why is the success method failing but the response from the server is fine?

API is written in python/django.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/getWords/?format=json&callback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success', data);
                $.each(data, function(i, foo) {
                    $list.append('<p>' + foo.word + '</p>')
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: `data.word` should be `data[word]`. If you use `data.word` JavaScript assumes `word` is a property of `data`. To resolve an argument or a variable to an Object property, use square brackets.

Comment: I fixed my error, it was a silly mistake. Ignoring the function to print the data to the page, I am not even able to get a console log or alert from the success method. My main question here is why would the response show up as fine with the JSON, but the success method of the call not be working? Thanks!

Comment: `return false;` at the bottom of your submit method, or your page will submit.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, can you elaborate on your last point? I've seen a bunch of examples of what I thought was a straight-forward simple call, and everyone seemed to have success without having to add a return false.